# htmlspecialchars won't accept 'variable variables' as an argument

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

I'm through reading a book: "PHP and MySQL ® Web Development 4th edition" by Luke Welling & Laura Thomson. On page 49. author suggest additional esoteric (for me at least) way to deal with form. Namely, if names in html form have same values which are distinct just by number incremented by one, we could use 'variable variables' type of variable in echo statment to dynamicaly extract values from The form...:

Here is my html:

```
<form action="processorder.php" method="post">
  <table style="border: 0px;">
    <tr style="background: #cccccc;">
      <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center;">Item</td>
      <td style="width: 15px; text-align: center;">Quantity</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tires</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="name1" size="3" maxlength="3" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Oil</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="name2" size="3" maxlength="3" /></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Spark Plugs</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="name3" size="3" maxlength="3" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;"><input type="submit" value="Submit Order" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <tr>
    <td>How did you find Bob's?</td>
    <td>
      <select name="find">
        <option value = "a">I'm a regular customer</option>
        <option value = "b">TV adversting</option>
        <option value = "c">Phone directory</option>
        <option value = "d">Word of mouth</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</form>
```

Here is my .php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bob's Auto Parts - Order Results</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Bob's Auto Parts</h1>
    <h2>Order Results</h2>
    <?php
      //create short variable names
      
      $tireqty  = $_POST['name1'];
      $oilqty   = $_POST['name2'];
      $sparkqty = $_POST['name3'];
      
      for ($i=1; $i <= 3; $i++){
        $temp = "name$i";
        echo htmlspecialchars($$temp).'<br />'; // or whatever processing we want to do
      }
      
      echo "<p>Order processed at ";
      echo date('H:i, jS F Y');// (string as an argument)
      echo "</p>";
      
      // or: 
      // echo "<p>Order processed at " . date('H:i, jS F Y') . "</p>";
      // (avoiding multiple echo commands)
      
      
      echo "<p>Your order is as follows: </p>";
      echo htmlspecialchars($tireqty)." tires<br />";
      echo htmlspecialchars($oilqty)." bottles of oil<br />";
      echo htmlspecialchars($sparkqty)." spark plugs<br />";
      
      $totalqty = 0;
      $totalqty = $tireqty + $oilqty + $sparkqty;
      echo "<p>Items ordered " . $totalqty . "<br />";
      $totalamount = 0.00;
      
      define('TIREPRICE', 100);
      define('OILPRICE', 10);
      define('SPARKPRICE', 4);
      $totalamount = $tireqty * TIREPRICE + $oilqty * OILPRICE + $sparkqty * SPARKPRICE;
      echo "Subtotal: $:" . number_format($totalamount, 2) . "<br />";
      
      $taxrate = 0.10;
      $totalamount = $totalamount * (1 + $taxrate);
      echo "Total including taxes is: $" . number_format($totalamount, 2) . "</p>";
      
      // echo 'isset($tireqty): '.isset($tireqty).'<br />';
      // echo 'isset($nothere): '.isset($nothere).'<br />';
      // echo 'empty($tireqty): '.empty($tireqty).'<br />';
      // echo 'empty($nothere): '.empty($nothere).'<br />';
      
      
      
      
    ?>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is where my problem is:

```
  for ($i=1; $i <= 3; $i++){
    $temp = "name$i";
    echo htmlspecialchars($$temp).'<br />'; 
  }
```

Script doesn't react nor accept parameter to be some other kind then simple variable. Even an editor (np++) doesn't accept second "$" sign.

Comment: Why don't you use an array instead of incrementing variable names? This has a lot of benefits in your code. Show us how your POST variables are created.

Comment: You don't have variables in your code called `$name1`, `$name2`, etc. `$$temp` should be `$_POST[$temp]` (though, as I said, an array would be much better)

Comment: As soon as you believe variable variables is the solution, then you got the problem wrong.

Comment: If you name all three inputs as `name="name[]"`, then `$_POST['name']` will be an array with the values from the inputs and you only need to do `foreach($_POST['name'] as $name) { echo htmlspecialchars($name); }`. It makes it a bit easier, cleaner and more readable.

Comment: I've changed original variables with "name1", "name2" and "name3" and now it works! Thank you! My POST variables are created (I guess) in time of filling-in three form fields and sending it to be processed by script. They are already in global POST array upon finishing filling the form?

Comment: If the book told you to write the code like that, you should immediately stop reading that book and throw it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This actually has nothing to do with the `htmlspecialchars()` function. When you write this in your loop:

```
$temp = "name$i"
```

You're creating a string with the value `name1`. When you then try to use it with a 'variable variable', like this:

```
$$temp
```

The code is looking for a variable called `$name1`, which does not exist.

All you really need to do to fix your original code is generate the key name you want to use from the `$_POST` array:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["name$i"]) . '<br />';
}
```

However, this is a somewhat inelegant solution anyway.

---

**A Better Solution**

You could start by changing your input names, so they all come into the `$_POST` array as their own numerically indexed array.

```
<tr>
    <td>Tyres</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name[]" size="3" maxlength="3" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Oil</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name[]" size="3" maxlength="3" /></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Spark Plugs</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name[]" size="3" maxlength="3" /></td>
</tr>
```

You can then loop through `$_POST['name']` and echo those values easily:

```
foreach ($_POST['name'] as $val) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($val) . '<br>';
}
```

---

Are either of these things an ideal solution? No, not really. You know you need a form field for tyres, oil and spark plugs, so trying to invoke a pattern where all the inputs are called `name` makes no sense in the first place. You would generally do this when the form fields all belong to one entity, or if you don't know how many rows there will be when the form is submitted.

What is `$_POST['name2']` or `$_POST['name'][1]`? Who knows. You have to read through your code and find the form to double check which field that belongs to.

Code should be semantic and easily understood by anyone reading it (including yourself, when you look back at your own code in the future).

I would rename the form inputs properly:

```
<tr>
    <td>Tyres</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="tyres" size="3" maxlength="3" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Oil</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="oil" size="3" maxlength="3" /></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Spark Plugs</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="spark_plugs" size="3" maxlength="3" /></td>
</tr>
```

And then everything becomes much more straightforward and understandable. In your code you have three values available. You know what they are, and what the names mean.

```
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['tyres']) . '<br>';
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['oil']) . '<br>';
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['spark_plugs']) . '<br>';
```

If you then want to use fancy loops and things with those, there's much I could go further into, but it's generally undesirable to over complicate everything. You end up producing more bugs, making your code more difficult for everyone to interpret, and making the process of debugging your code more time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in that example was `htmlspecialchars()` function. Because the parameter `$$temp` is `undefined` and `$temp` variable is just a string named `name` concatenating with integer values such as 1,2,3. But the real value is in global `$_POST[$temp]` variable. To get the value in `$_POST[$temp]` you need to use right post parameter name and in your example it is named as `name1`, `name2` and `name3`.

```
  // There are many other ways but Let me do this way.
  // Incoming Post Values that are named name1,name2 and name3

  $tireqty  = $_POST['name1'];
  $oilqty   = $_POST['name2'];
  $sparkqty = $_POST['name3'];

  for ($i=1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
      $temp = "name$i";
      $temp = !isset($_POST[$temp]) ? "" : $_POST[$temp];
      echo htmlspecialchars($temp).'<br />'; 
  }
  
  // if you want to stick with variable variable technique.

  $name1 = $_POST['name1'];
  $name2 = $_POST['name2'];
  $name3 = $_POST['name3'];

  for ($i=1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
      $temp = "name$i";
      echo htmlspecialchars($$temp).'<br />'; 
  }
```

Comment: Interesting but (at least) "scary" at first glance...

Comment: G*d d** it if it's complicated it must be clever. At least by some comments my understanding would somehow be accelerated...

Comment: Why should we "do this way"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Okay, let me explain the problem in that example was htmlspecialchars() function. Because the parameter $$temp is undefined and $temp variable is just a string named "name" concatenating with integer values such as 1,2,3. But the real value is in global $_POST[$temp] variable. To get the value in $_POST[$temp] you need to use right post parameter name and in your example it is named as name1,name2 and name3.

Comment: Put the explanation in your post so it becomes searchable for future visitors to SO.

Comment: And this book that you read is totally not recommended at first glance. Instead of iterating by for loop. it could be done many other ways using safe arrays and good sanitizing scripts